# Filtering content by category(many to many field) using django

Tags: python, django

I would like to filter the items on my website using category. I have managed to do filtering by the title, but I am not sure about this one.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  price = models.FloatField()
  discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
  label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  description = models.TextField()
  image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.all()
  category_list = Category.objects.all()
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query:
    item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

  paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)
  page = request.GET.get('page')

  try:
      items = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      items = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {
      'items': items,
      'category': category_list
  }
return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

home.html

```
<form method="GET" action=".">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select id="cat" class="form-control" name="cat">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                {% for cat in category %}
                <option value="{{ cat }}">{{ cat }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Currently the page displays the categories in a list and below theres  {% for item in items %} statement witch displays all the items and they can be filtered only by the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think it is better to use the `cat.pk` as value for an option:

```
<option value="{{ cat.pk }}">{{ cat }}</option>
```

Now we can filter on the category as well:

```
def HomeView(request):
    item_list = Item.objects.all()
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        item_list = item_list.filter(title__icontains=query)

    cat = request.GET.get('cat')
    if cat:
        item_list = item_list.filter(category__pk=cat)

    paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'items': items,
        'category': category_list
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, everything works superb. I have got one more question, do you know what would I have to do, to filter the products by the category and lets say price at the same time? 2 queries would have to work at the same time I suppose?

Comment: @Menor: you filter the `item_list` further with `item_list = item_list.filter(price=myprice)`, or `item_list = item_list.filter(price__range=(min_price, max_price)`, with `myprice`, `min_price`, and `max_price` of course expressions you need to fill in yourself :).

Comment: Ok thanks. One more thing, I have got a problem with the category list, when I click search button and there's no category selected (its on "Choose..) i am getting an error. How I can make it so it ignores this value?

Comment: @Menor: I think you better set a `value=""` (the empty string) for that `<option>`, otherwise it will use the text, and that will indeed not work.

Comment: Thank you for your help and fast replies

Comment: coming again with a question, is there a way to store the entered values (category, price, title) in the form after the products are filtered? After clicking the search button the form is empty